# Random in mysql2 for rails 4 app

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I'm using `@places = Place.all.limit(2).order("RANDOM()")` for my app in production server and it working ok, but with passenger it showing me an error `ActionView::Template::Error (Mysql2::Error: FUNCTION daysandnights.RANDOM does not exist: SELECT`places`.* FROM`places`ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 2):`.

How can i fix this issue? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use `RAND()` https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_rand

Answer (score 0):

@gotva, your answer can work.

Specifically, when production I use rand(), when development I use random().

```
if Rails.env.production? 
  scope :random8, -> { limit(8).order("RAND()") }
elsif Rails.env.development? 
  scope :random8, -> { limit(8).order("RANDOM()") }
end
```